# how to get the title of a NSURl link without UIWebView

Tags: ios, nsurl

Is it possible to get the title of a NSURL link without UIWebView ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJBFBJC) to get the content of the link and then parse it using `NSXMLParser` to get the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the content which the URL points to and parse the HTML for the title element, but that won't account for changes to the title as a result of javascript execution. So the answer is 'no', there isn't any way to **reliably** get the title of a page which is at a given URL.